# C++ runtime of function with different declarations

Tags: c++, performance, getter-setter

Is there any runtime difference between these two ways of declaration:

1) *.h

```
int GetVal () { return val; }
```

2) *.h

```
 int GetVal ();
```

*.cpp

```
 int GetVal () { return val; }
```

getters\setters are called often and it is an important perfomance question.

Comment: Outside containers getters/setters are bad

Comment: Did you try benchmarking the two approaches?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no, i hope smbdy knows that

Comment: Just to clarify, is it performance differences you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

As a general statement there is no difference.

Nevertheless different compilers with different flag may generate different code.

The most important point - will compiler inline the call or not.

In some cases docs for compiler may give a clue. It makes sense to take a look.

Try using `inline` keyword or `__inline` for MS compiler and check the binary.

Comment: >The most important point - will compiler inline the call or not.

yep, and that is the question, how can i find out this?

Comment: @Greag.Deay that largely depends on the compiler, version & compilaton options used, and you can find out by yourself by looking at the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the compiler options, the getter will be inlined, and the .h function will be as fast as a pointer redirection.

If you put your code in the cpp, you will need a far more aggresive optimization to get this

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are declaring a class, as it is quite different otherwise.

```
// in your .h
int GetVal () { return val; }
```

This both defines the function as inline and declares it.

```
// in your .h
int GetVal ();
```

This is just a declaration.

```
// in your .cpp
int Class::GetVal () { return val; }
```

This is a definition of the method.